# Starting a windows file system attribute "hidden" application in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am trying to launch a hidden file attribute in visual basic 6, but VB6 does not recognize the hidden file attribute that I targeted my application to start... On the other hand, when I take off hide file attribute, VB6 recognizes the file.

My question is

**How can I manage to make my VB6.0 application start a hidden file attribute application?**

Here is what I tried:

`Shell("Explorer.exe " & "hiddenapplication.exe", vbHide)`

**Note**: Assume that **"hiddenapplication.exe"** is the hidden file attribute, it is the file that I targeted my application to open this file only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The `vbHide` constant has no relation to the hidden file attribute. `Shell()` can also run an executable regardless of the file attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will check if the file is in hidden attribute and will open it normally.

This code is also tested and 100% working!

```
Dim Res
Dim Filename

Filename = App.Path + "\hiddenapplication.exe"

If Dir("hiddenapplication.exe", vbHidden) <> "" Then
    Res = Shell("Explorer.exe " & Filename, vbHide)
    MsgBox "hiddenapplication.exe found and is now opened!"
End If
```

Comment: This code worked like a charm!